# Soup find() returning None when element type is specified

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Why does soup has trouble finding that div in the html content?

```
       <div class="test class" dir="auto">
        test test
        Premiere
        <a href="...">
         details
        </a>
       </div>
```

Code to find the div:

```
result_div = soup.find('div', string=re.compile('Premiere'))
```

which returns None, but not specifying the 'div' type:

```
result_div = soup.find(string=re.compile('Premiere'))
```

works - it finds an element and its type is **<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>**.

The html output I used above is what soup effectively sees (I printed it just before find() call), so it is not dynamic elements loading issue.

Comment: It's returning the text node, not the div.